# Mysql query with dynamic pivoting

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table

I have one table named grades like this:

```
  +--------+--------+-----------+
  | userid | itemid | finalgrade|
  +--------+--------+-----------+
  |  1     |   7    |    100    | 
  |  1     |   8    |    89     |    
  |  2     |   7    |    87     |     
  |  2     |   8    |    17     |    
  |  3     |   7    |    87     |   
  |  3     |   8    |    38     |   
  +--------+--------+-----------+
```

And I want to create a pivot query that changes me the table like this:

```
  +--------+---+---+
  | userid | 7 | 8 |
  +--------+---+---+
  |  1     |100| 89| 
  |  2     |87 | 17|        
  |  3     |87 | 38|    
  +--------+---+---+
```

I have one solution, using defined itemid like this one:

```
select *,
truncate (sum(finalgrade*(1-abs(sign(itemid-7)))),0) as 7,
truncate (sum(finalgrade*(1-abs(sign(itemid-8)))),0) as 8,
FROM grades
group by userid"
```

The problem is that I need the same query but with not defined itemid, dynamically creating columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want a query like this:

```
SELECT userid,
  MAX(CASE WHEN itemid=7 THEN finalgrade END) as c7,
  MAX(CASE WHEN itemid=8 THEN finalgrade END) as c8,
FROM grades
GROUP BY userid
```

but you want it with dynamic values, and then you could use a prepared statement like this:

```
SELECT    
  CONCAT(    
    'SELECT userid,',    
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN itemid=', itemid, ' THEN finalgrade END) AS c', itemid)),    
    ' FROM tablename GROUP BY userid')    
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT itemid FROM tablename) s INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

You could use SUM instead of MAX, depending on how your data is structured.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but the query have a syntax error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt' at line 8.`

Comment: @EnriqueBerrueta it looks correct to me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e8f4/1 is itemid a INT column?

Comment: Yes, item id is INT. I was using sqlfiddle and surprise me because its correct, the problem is when i use it in phpmyadmin or in php.

Comment: @EnriqueBerrueta do you have a lot of different itemids? group_concat has a length limit and i suspect that the query might have been cut... but this limit can be modified using `set group_concat_max_len=<new limit>;` its default is 1024 you could try with 10000...

Comment: Yes, this help me a little, but now the query gives me another error: `Unknown prepared statement handler (stmt) given to EXECUTE`

Comment: @EnriqueBerrueta the first query should return a text column with the actual query that you need to execute, can you execute it without INTO sql and see if the query that it returns is fine?

Comment: First query returns 1 column with the query's.

Comment: if i use it throught putty mysql works. The problem is just on phpmyadmin and in php.